# How can I find the command line program STM32_Programmer_CLI.exe to write into the flash of STM32F429?

Tags: stm32, bin, flash-memory, utility

I'm working with the ST demo board NUCLEO-F429ZI and I'm studying the example [Nx_WebServer](https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/x-cube-azrtos-f4/tree/main/Projects/STM32F429ZI-Nucleo/Applications/NetXDuo/Nx_WebServer) to develop a my own project.
The readme file of the example explains how to write the binary file `web_demo.bin` into the flash memory of the microprocessor STM32F429.
The file `web_demo.bin` contains all the files that build the website created by the application.
The readme file proposes to use the following command:

```
<INSTALL_PATH>STM32CubeProgrammer\bin\STM32_Programmer_CLI.exe -c port=swd -w <INSTALL_PATH>web_content\web_demo.bin 0x08100000 -v
```

After many research I didn't find the program `STM32_Programmer_CLI.exe`, but for example I have found this [post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/653317/stm32-multiple-addresses-and-bin-files/653378#653378) which says that `STM32_Programmer_CLI.exe` is *the command line interface of the program* [STM32CubeProgrammer](https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stm32cubeprog.html).

I have already downloaded the program `STM32CubeProgrammer` by the [the previous link](https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stm32cubeprog.html), but it doesn't provide the command line interface `STM32_Programmer_CLI.exe`.

How can I find the program `STM32_Programmer_CLI.exe`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the help of @Armandas I have found the program `STM32_Programmer_CLI.exe` (see his comment in [his answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/653317/stm32-multiple-addresses-and-bin-files/653378#653378)).

As I have written in the question this program is the command line interface of the program [STM32CubeProgrammer](https://www.st.com/en/development-tools/stm32cubeprog.html) and is installed togheter with that graphical program.
I didn't find it only because the folder where it is installed was not in my PATH variable (Windows system).

The installation folder is:

```
<INSTALL_PATH>STM32CubeProgrammer\bin\
```

where `INSTALL_PATH` (in my system) is `C:\Program Files\STMicroelectromics\STM32Cube\`.

### Conclusion

The readme file of the example [Nx_WebServer](https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/x-cube-azrtos-f4/tree/main/Projects/STM32F429ZI-Nucleo/Applications/NetXDuo/Nx_WebServer) **is absolutely correct**.